# VSCode creating string in c++ doesn't work

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

Trying to figure out why creating an instance of a string results in my program being shut down...
My simple program is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main(){
    std::cout << "HELLO" << std::endl;
    std::string str("str");
    return 0;
}
```

My problem is that this program prints nothing. However:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main(){
    std::cout << "HELLO" << std::endl;
    // std::string str("str");
    return 0;
}
```

works perfectly fine and prints "HELLO".

I'm compiling with mingw this way: `g++ main.cpp -o main.exe` (doesn't show any errors)

I've tried using the string in any way (like printing it). In general I'm trying to create a string instance to do `std::cin>>` into it.

Help will be much appreciated! Thank you

Comment: [Cannot reproduce...](https://tio.run/##Sy4o0E3OScxL//9fOTMvOac0JVXBJjO/uKQoNTHXjgshBhTJzEu34@LKzCtRyE3MzNPQrOZSAILikhQrq@T80hIFGxsFJQ9XHx9/JRATLJ6al5JjjVAGMQTILtJQAhJKmhC5otSS0qI8BQNrrtr//wE "C++ (clang) – Try It Online")

Comment: Tried debugging by stepping through each line?

Comment: Try placing `std::cin.ignore(100000, '\n');` before the `return` statement

Comment: It should work. Maybe you have a broken Mingw installation. Try getting it via MSYS2.

Answer (score 0):

Works for me:

```
$ cat test.cpp 
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main(){
    std::cout << "HELLO" << std::endl;
    std::string str("str");
    return 0;
}

$ g++ test.cpp 
$ ./a.out 
HELLO
$
```

The problem is elsewhere in your system, the code is OK.